# Getting error with CupertinoDatePicker: initial minute is not divisible by minute interval

Tags: flutter, dart

Trying to have a simple `CupertinoDatePicker`. When I set `minuteInterval`, I get an error:

> The following assertion was thrown building TimePicker(dirty):
> initial minute is not divisible by minute interval

```
CupertinoDatePicker(
      onDateTimeChanged: (DateTime newDate) => print('changed'),
      mode: CupertinoDatePickerMode.time,
      initialDateTime: DateTime.now(),
      minuteInterval: 5,
    )
```

Seems like the minutes for DateTime.now() has to be divisible by 5.

How do I make sure the times minutes either end with 0 or 5 whichever is later?
so say it's 7:42,  the minute should be 45. If the minute is 47, it should be 50?

Comment: this is open issue see https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/60456

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here's how to do it:

```
if (initialDateTime.minute % 5 != 0) {
      initialMinute = initialDateTime.minute - initialDateTime.minute % 5 + 5;
    }
```

and here's the full code:

```
DateTime initialDateTime = DateTime.now();
    int initialMinute = initialDateTime.minute;

    if (initialDateTime.minute % 5 != 0) {
      initialMinute = initialDateTime.minute - initialDateTime.minute % 5 + 5;
    }

CupertinoDatePicker(...
initialDateTime: DateTime(initialDateTime.year, initialDateTime.month, initialDateTime.day, initialDateTime.hour, initialMinute),
)
```

Answer (score 4):

Change the initialDateTime to be divisible by 5.

```dart
DateTime now = DateTime.now();

CupertinoDatePicker(
        onDateTimeChanged: (DateTime newDate) => print('changed'),
        mode: CupertinoDatePickerMode.time,
        initialDateTime: DateTime(now.year, now.month, now.day, now.hour, (now.minute % 5 * 5).toInt()),
        minuteInterval: 5,
      )
```